# placing images next to each other with text below

Tags: css, image, css-float

I'm looking for a way to put 2 images next to each other horizontally with text below each image that sticks with that image. This should be responsive. I've tried the code of several other posts on this website related to this issue, but none of the examples worked for me (each proposition did not place the pictures next to one another, but below one another. This is what I got so far:

```css
#design-cast {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.member {
    float: left;
    width: 40%;
    margin: 1% 1% 45px 1%;
}

.name {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
}

.member img {
    width: 40%;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="design-cast">
    <div class="member">
        <img width="40%" src="image-02.jpg" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" alt="Responsive image" />
        <div class="name">Name
            <br />Description</div>
    </div>
    <div class="member">
        <img width="40%" src="image-02.jpg" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" alt="Responsive image" />
        <div class="name">Name
            <br />Description</div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: What you have now puts the images in a horizontal row with text below and everything is responsive and scales. Can you be more specific about what isn't working and what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi, the images don't appear next to each other but below each other. I really want them placed next to each other.

Comment: they look next to each other to me http://i.imgur.com/P0b0U2f.png

Comment: yes, I mean on my website :-)

Comment: I have placed the css in Google tag manager because I don't have access to the website code (CMS = Drupal). Could that be the reason why it doesn't work properly?

Answer (score 1):

use flexbox

```css
body {
  margin: 0
}

#design-cast {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.member {
  flex: 0 48%;
  margin: 1% 1% 45px 1%;
}

.member img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

@media (max-width:480px) {
  .member {
    flex: 0 100%
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="design-cast">
  <div class="member">
    <img src="//placehold.it/1000" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" alt="Responsive image" />
    <div class="name">Name
      <br />Description</div>
  </div>
  <div class="member">
    <img src="//placehold.it/1000" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" alt="Responsive image" />
    <div class="name">Name
      <br />Description</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use bootstrap thumbnail for your desired result. 
Check this code. This will target all devices from 320px.

```css
.img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row">

  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">

    <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT8dwkxQJ8PkFjeU8fb1bIXtEcsqoIoRztPOCWPnRb1np9iO0e2341WWqoj" class="img">
        <div class="caption">
          <h4>Name</h4>
          <h4>Description</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT8dwkxQJ8PkFjeU8fb1bIXtEcsqoIoRztPOCWPnRb1np9iO0e2341WWqoj" class="img">
      <div class="caption">
        <h4>Name</h4>
        <h4>Description</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

</div>
```